# How to save file as "read-only" from Delphi?

Tags: file, delphi, save

I would like to save a file as a "read-only" file. Is it possible?

Comment: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FileSetAttr.html

Answer (score 5):

Save it as normal, f.ex. via

```
VAR S : TFileStream;
.
S := TFileStream.Create(FileName,fmCreate);
<Write to stream>
S.Free;
```

Then

```
USES SysUtils;

// Set R/O
IF FileSetAttr(FileName,FileGetAttr(FileName) or faReadOnly)<>NO_ERROR THEN
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

afterwards to mark it as "Read/Only".

If you want to update it later on, you need to remove the Read/Only flag first:

```
// Set R/W
IF FileSetAttr(FileName,FileGetAttr(FileName) AND NOT faReadOnly)<>NO_ERROR THEN
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

then update the file, then mark it as Read/Only again.

Comment: You should add some error checking to this code. The ability to do this is one advantage of using `FileSetAttr` over `IOUtils`. Bloody IOUtils! In fact you can't even reliably add error checking for `FileSetAttr` in case the API call fails but doesn't set last error. If I were doing this I would call the winapi function directly.

Comment: Both `FileGetAttr` and `FileSetAttr` can fail

Comment: Yes, but if FileGetAttr fails, FileSetAttr will fail as well in all cases that I can see...

Comment: That's probably true but I personally would prefer not to have to second guess the api

Answer (score 5):

This is a two stage process, that is only available on the Windows platform.

1. Save the file.
2. Add the read-only attribute to the file's metadata.

Assuming that you already know how to do stage 1, let's consider stage 2. Using the `System.IOUtils` unit you set this attribute like so:

```
uses
  System.IOUtils;
....
var
  attributes: TFileAttributes;
....
attributes := TFile.GetAttributes(FileName);
Include(attributes, faReadOnly);
TFile.SetAttributes(FileName, attributes);
```

If you wish to remove the read-only attribute then you use exactly the same code but replace `Include` with `Exclude`.

For platforms other than Windows, you can still use `TFile.GetAttributes` and `TFile.SetAttributes`, but the available attributes are very different, reflecting the different filesystem models of Windows and the POSIX platforms.

---

Unfortunately the RTL fails to provide any way to check for errors in this code. So if you want to check for errors (you should) then you are actually best calling the Windows API function `SetFileAttributes` directly. You might do that like this:

```
function FileSetAttribute(const FileName: string; const Attr: DWORD; const Value: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  Flags, NewFlags: DWORD;
begin
  Flags := GetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName));
  if Flags=INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then begin
    Result := False;
  end else begin
    if Value then begin
      NewFlags := Flags or Attr
    end else begin
      NewFlags := Flags and not Attr;
    end;
    Result := (NewFlags=Flags) or SetFileAttributes(PChar(FileName), NewFlags);
  end;
end;

function FileSetReadOnly(const FileName: string; ReadOnly: Boolean): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileSetAttribute(FileName, faReadOnly, ReadOnly);
end;
```

As discussed previously this code is for Windows only. The `FileSetReadOnly` function returns a boolean indicating whether or not it succeeded. In case of failure, you can then call `GetLastError` for extended error information.

Comment: Only for modern Delphis that has TPath. For a version that supports all(?) versions of Delphi, see my answer.

Comment: @HeartWare yes, there was me assuming that IOUtils would wrap it all up properly and raise an exception. By now I should know better than to trust IOUtils to do anything right!